# dyld crash when enabling module stability for Swift binary framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to enable module stability for my binary Swift framework.

My setup is as follows:

- Xcode 11.1
- Enabled "Build Libraries for Distribution" option

I have validated that the outputted .framework does include the necessary .swiftinterface files within the framework, so in theory I reckon it should work.

However, when I attempt to use this framework from any app, `dyld` crashes on launch with `__abort_with_payload`.

I have tried this in the following cases:

- Raw framework compiled by Xcode (.framework format)
- `lipo`d fat framework (.framework format)
- New XCFramework (.xcframework) format

In all cases I've tested, enabling this option seems to cause the app to crash on launch.

The only thing that comes to mind is that my framework is a that my framework itself depends on other 3rd party (non-binary) frameworks, which are compiled-in via Cocoapods.

In the [WWDC '19 talk on Binary Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/) we are told that "all of your Dependencies do have to be built with the Build Libraries for Distribution build setting in order to get that binary compatibility guarantee that we talked about" -- however this does not make clear whether it's possible to build just the binary framework itself with module stability, and have the dependencies built from source.

I have also tried enabling "Build Libraries for Distribution" in the Pods sub-project build settings, but this still does not resolve the issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked out how to fix this.

As suggested (but not terribly clear) in the WWDC talk, it seems that all library dependencies **must** have the "Build Libraries for Distribution" build setting enabled.

## Cocoapods

Cocoapods [does not currently](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9148) have built-in support for this (or XCFrameworks, for that matter), however, this can temporarily be hacked around by adding the following to your app's Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
      end
    end
end
```

This will ensure that all dependencies are built for distribution.

## Carthage

Carthage [doesn't yet](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/pull/2881) support module stability either. You need to pass custom Xcode build settings to ensure that when you run `carthage build`, your frameworks are built with "Build Libraries for Distribution" enabled:

```
echo 'BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES'>/tmp/config.xcconfig; XCODE_XCCONFIG_FILE=/tmp/config.xcconfig carthage build; rm /tmp/config.xcconfig
```

Comment: I have a similar setup, integrated through Cocoapods. But when I apply your solution I get a compiler error saying `cannot load underlying module for <dependency_setup_through_cocoapods>` inside the .swiftinterface file of the Binary framework that I've built((

Comment: can you help with Carthage i havent use it much and want to set BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION this flag